# Warning message regarding stack size

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, stack

I use `Visual Studio 2010` with `Code Analysis` activated. In my code there's a line allocating some memory in a function:

```
TCHAR someString[40000];
```

The code analysis throws a warning message:

> warning C6262: Function uses '40000' bytes of stack: exceeds /analyze:stacksize'16384'. Consider moving some data to heap

I wonder if I should take the warning serious. Do I have to face some real trouble if I allocate some memory on the stack > 16384? Or is it just a general warning message which reminds me that I have to take care for my stack size in general? As far as I know the default stack size is 1MB (if you use Visual Studio).

Comment: I haven't any problems with that

Comment: If this function doesn't use recursion and is the only function that allocates a lot of stack memory, it should be fine. Still, you might want to consider moving it to the heap, just in case.

Comment: @MichaelXanadu: There is nice explanation about this on MSDN page:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yhee2f0.aspx .On this page suggestion has been given to use raw heap memory or better STL container as std::string std::vector<TCHAR> in this case.

Answer (score 8):

Admittedly, that message can be confusing since VS (project properties) does report that the default is 1M.  However, if you look at the text of the [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yhee2f0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you'll note that the limit is actually 16k for Code Analysis.  Follow the steps at the bottom of that link to correct the warning.

Comment: So the stack size IS really 1MB and the warning message will be thrown each time the stack size exceeds a defined threshold (e.g. 16K)?

Comment: Yes. For Code Analysis purposes, unless you change it, the stack size is 16k.  You can override that limit when performing the analysis.

Comment: @rrirower: not quite.  Code analysis doesn't consider the stack to be 16k, it merely considers it suspicious when a single function uses more than 16k of the stack.  That's quite different.  OTOH I really wish the warning would list the largest variables on the stack for me :/

Answer (score 2):

I found that such warnings must be taken seriously.
I had a declaration

> ```
> { // some local branch deep inside a function 
> char T[2000000];  
>   ...
> }
> ```

left by mistake somewhere deep inside a big function. The function always crashed immediatly after entry to the function, even if the declaration in the local branch was far away, and I never got there with the debugger. 
It was difficult to find in MS Visual Studio, even when code analysis gave me a warning.